# Entry point of an app in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, entry-point

I started a new iOS project in Xcode. File-new-SingleViewApp

Then I selected the following files

[image]

and moved to the trash.
Then I removed the following keys from the *Info.plist* file:
[image]

Then I added a C file named *main.c*
The content of the *main.c* file is:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

        print("hello");
}
```

And surpirsingly this works, the app compiles and run and writes "hello" to console. My question is: Was not **main.m** (and not main.c) supossed to be the entry point of an app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no rule about the filename or its suffix: only about the function name *main*. Your file can be written in C or Objective-C, so its suffix can be *.c* or *.m*. An Objective-C program, after all, is a C program; Objective-C is C.

However, notice that your app is now unable to use Cocoa for anything. It is, in effect, not an app. It never calls `UIApplicationMain`. It just runs its one line and quits. So it's kind of silly.

A more productive way to get started on what you're doing would be to use the macOS Command Line Tool template. Observe that you can choose to write it in C! What you have constructed is *very* like a C command-line tool (except that there are no iOS command-line tools).

Comment: To be slightly clearer in the first sentence: the "name main" refers to the *function*, not the file. The system does not care if your "main()-defining file" is named `myapp.m` or `superawesome.c` as long as exactly one thing defines `main()`.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks as always; I'll tweak.